# put element out of bootstrap backdrop

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div id='header'>
    <button style="z-index:9999"></button>
    <div class="modal-backdrop am-fade"></div>
</div>
```

I have a html look like this, and the modal-backdrop covers the whole page. But I want to show this particular button, and I add `z-index` of the button to `9999`, but it didn't work. The backdrop's `z-index` is `1040`, is there anything I need to do with it? And I'm writing a directive with angular js, and I append the backdrop in the directive so the `<div>` for the modal-backdrop should be inside the header and at the same level with `<button>`. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `z-index` to work, you need to define an appropriate `position` rule with it. An example may include...

```
button {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

See [CSS z-index Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) for more information

> z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute,
>   position:relative, or position:fixed).